# APS template with package italian babel

Tags: babel, journal

I'm trying to use `\usepackage[italian]{babel}` with this journal template: https://it.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/aps

But i get errors on `\maketitle` (4 errors):

```
! Missing $ inserted.
! Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode.
! You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode.
```

How can i solve that?

Comment: Welcome, out of interest, are submissions in italian to the APS allowed?

Comment: How can i check that? @Johannes_B

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, please provide a [minimal working exaple](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html).

Comment: If you download the tex file and add the line `\usepackage[italian]{babel}`, you get all compiled?

Comment: Seems like sharelatex was too lazy to properly show me something, or i was to stupid. Usually, i don't use the online editors.

Comment: Of course, i am using TexMaker to edit it locally

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in `italian.ldf` and should be reported.

The problem is that the `revtex4-1` class activates the comma, but `italian.ldf` assigns a different meaning than the class expects. Here is a workaround.

```
\documentclass[
 aps,
]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

%% work around the bad interaction between revtex and babel-italian
\makeatletter
\let\it@comma@def\active@comma
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\author{Ann Author}
\altaffiliation{a, b}
\affiliation{c, d}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]